# How do you make your else statement do nothing?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm new to programming in JavaScript, and I need help!
I am making a small program that randomly selects a number (1-4) and then prints out a statement based on the number. A=1, 2=B, 3=C, and 4=D. My problem is that with my if/else statements, I want the else statement to do nothing. How? (Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to JS) The code is:

```
 var randomGuess=Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1);
            if (randomGuess===1) {
                document.write("Try A."); }
                else { 
                return false }
            if (randomGuess===2) {
                document.write("Try B.") }
                else {
                return false }
            if (randomGuess===3) {
                document.write("Try C.") } 
                else {
                return false }
            if (randomGuess===4) {
                document.write("Try D.") } 
                else {
                return false }
```

Comment: Simply remove `else { return false }`.

Comment: Notice that there is a big diference between `else {}` and `else {return false}`
In the second case the function will stop in the else scenario.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

an `if` doesn't need an `else` always .. so remove it.

```
if(){ ...}
if(){ ...}
if(){ ...}
```

is fine , but its adviced to use `switch` in this case.

[`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) works better in this kind of situation

Comment: Not exactly, switch performs a `==`comparison whereas he is using the `===`operator here.

Answer (score 5):

The proper method of having a code block do nothing, is having a comment inside it.

```
if(1 == 2) {
  a = 8;
}
else {
  // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The usual do nothing statment is `;` One example would be:

```
for (var i=0; i<100; i++); // iterates to 100 but does nothing
```

With that said, the else statement of an if is optional, so if you don't need it, don't write it:

```
if (randomGuess===1) document.write("Try A."); 
if (randomGuess===2) document.write("Try B.");
if (randomGuess===3) document.write("Try C.");
```

Answer (score 4):

I see you got your answer. I will suggest you to use switch in such cases. Saves execution time.

```
    switch(randomGuess) {
        case 1: 
          document.write("Try A.");
        case 2:
          document.write("Try B.");
        case 3:
          document.write("Try C.");
        case 4:
          document.write("Try D.");
        default:
          /* return error*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just leave out the `else` statement altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question, just remove the `else {}` block, but going a bit further, try to use other structures, like `elseif` or switch(): http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/switch.shtml

It's important to make the program work, but if it's easy to read is much better ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to leave it empty, you could also invert the statement, or another alternative might be to use `elseif`

So you could use:

```
       if (randomGuess===1) {
            document.write("Try A."); }
        if (randomGuess===2) {
            document.write("Try B.") }
        if (randomGuess===3) {
            document.write("Try C.") } 
        if (randomGuess===4) {
            document.write("Try D.") }
```

Or:

```
        if (randomGuess===1) {
            document.write("Try A."); }
        else if (randomGuess===2) {
            document.write("Try B.") }
        else if (randomGuess===3) {
            document.write("Try C.") } 
        else if (randomGuess===4) {
            document.write("Try D.") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just say  `... else{ ; }`

This returns NOTHING.